# TFS - Upgrade SQL Server Version

Tags: tfs, sql-server-2016

Tools:
TFS 2012
Sql Server 2008

We are looking at upgrading SQL Server from 2008 to Sql Server 2016

Will TFS 2012 work with an SQL Server 2016 back end?

Answer (score 0):

TFS 2012 is not compatible with SQL Server 2016, it's not supported, you can only use SQL Server 2012 or SQL Server 2008 R2.

Please see [Requirements and compatibility](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/setup-admin/requirements#sql-server) for details.

If you want to use Sql Server 2016 you have to upgrade TFS to 2015 Update 3 or later versions.

See [Upgrade your deployment to the latest version of TFS](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/setup-admin/tfs/upgrade/get-started) for details.